# ASP.NET Identity Changing Password Signs User Out

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-identity, change-password

I have an issue with the ASP.NET Identity provider. I started with the default template that comes with Visual Studio 2019, targeting .NET 4.7.2 WebForms.

On the change password page, the Identity provider doesn't seem to be updating the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` to reflect the new `SecurityStamp`. I can see in Fiddler that ASP.NET is sending a 302 to redirect back to the Manage.aspx page and it is sending an auth cookie, that presumably should reflect the new `SecurityStamp` that results from the password change, except that it doesn't. So the user is immediately logged out of the application after a password or 2FA change, since I have `validateInterval` set to `TimeSpan.Zero`. If I set it to another value, the user's cookie becomes invalid after that value, regardless of the actual age the cookie is supposed to have.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            .SlidingExpiration = True,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                    validateInterval:=TimeSpan.Zero,
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})
```

And here is the relevant code in the change password page:

```
Protected Sub ChangePassword_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
        Dim result As IdentityResult = manager.ChangePassword(User.Identity.GetUserId(), CurrentPassword.Text, NewPassword.Text)
        If result.Succeeded Then
            Dim userInfo = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
            signInManager.SignIn(userInfo, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
            Response.Redirect("~/Profile/Manage?m=ChangePwdSuccess")
        Else
            AddErrors(result)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to log the user out and then log them back in:

```
Protected Sub ChangePassword_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then
        Dim userManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
        Dim authenticateResult = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie).GetAwaiter.GetResult()
        Dim accountChangeResult As IdentityResult = userManager.ChangePassword(User.Identity.GetUserId(), CurrentPassword.Text, NewPassword.Text)
        If accountChangeResult.Succeeded Then
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
            Dim userInfo = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
            signInManager.SignIn(userInfo, isPersistent:=authenticateResult.Properties.IsPersistent, rememberBrowser:=False)
            Response.Redirect("~/Profile/Manage?m=ChangePwdSuccess")
        Else
            AddErrors(accountChangeResult)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```